# What 'this' refer to in here?

Tags: java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RelativeLayout myLayout=new RelativeLayout(this);
        Button myButton=new Button(this);

        myLayout.addView(myButton);
        setContentView(myLayout);

    }
```

Comment: could you explain more your issue? And please update the title to provide more information. In Java 'this' refers to the class instance.

Comment: So does it mean that in my above case it refers to the object of class MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

this refers to the object which you are calling the method.
When you will create an object,  suppose obj and then call obj.onCreate (),  this will be a reference to obj.

Comment: I get that it refers to the obj. But it looks complex for me in above case.In my question, 'this' refers to MainActivity class ?

Comment: It refers to object and not class. And that object will be an instance of MainActivity